# Suppress Firebase Firestore function triggers in batch write

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to suppers function trigger for a specific entry in the write batch ?

```
batch.update(docRef1,docUpdate1)
batch.update(docRef2,docUpdate2,{ skipTriggers: true}
batch.set(docRef3,docSet,{ skipTriggers: true}
```

It would be greater to have the option to skip triggers when updating large number of documents because it takes a lot of time and the current solution that requires to delete the trigger/s makes the production application unusable until the update process is completed

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question. Can you check if that helps.

Comment: sorry to say but, even  tho your answer is 100% correct, it does not help at all :))))

Comment: It is hard to understand with a single line of question why you are expecting it to work and what are your requirements. Please provide additional information like your use case and more details  by editing the question,Alternatively you may file a support ticket with your use case and expected behavior at [link](https://cloud.google.com/contact#:~:text=Get%20support%20for%20my%20current%20Google%20Cloud%20product(s))

Comment: the question / request is simple: update firebase documents without triggering the functions. in my specific case a granular solution was needed to select what document inside a write batch could trigger functions, how "we" plan to use the requested feature is irrelevant in my humble opinion

Comment: Have a look at this similar [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314716/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-firebase-functions-firestore-triggers).

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no feature to suppers function trigger for a specific entry in the write batch.
Have a look at this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) for batched writes

If you think it’s a valid feature request you may raise [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) with a clear description why you are thinking it’s a feature request. Good feature requests will solve common problems or enable new use cases.